# React useEffect with handleScroll

Tags: javascript, react.js

This is a basic React problem, how to handle global listener and change state in callback without attaching a listener on each rerender.

Here is a common solution:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            var rect = selectedRingElement.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            if(isElementInViewport(rect)) {
                console.log(`${isInViewPort} ${initialViewPortTop}`)
                if(!isInViewPort&&!initialViewPortTop) {
                    setInitialViewPortTop(rect.top)
                }
                setIsInViewport(true)
            } else {
                setIsInViewport(false)
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
          }
    }, [initialViewPortTop, isInViewPort])
```

So it works and shouldn't create memory leaks, however I find it not nice to have to remove et add event listener all the time. Do you know a cleaner solution to this problem, or is it the best we can do?